# How to add class 'reverse' to dropdown-menu dynamically on dropdown click?

Tags: javascript, angular, drop-down-menu, position, dropdown

I am looking for a solution to add class `reverse` from ts file to show dropdown upward when it's near or in the bottom position.

On dropdown click, it gives me *null* for `dropdown-menu` in the console.
For now I am adding it through html, in addition it require a boolean variable to check for it's position. So, I am using many dropdowns in my project and I do not want to add such redundent approach every where.
Further, after its solution, I have to make a directive to use globally in my project.

Below is my code:

*app.component.ts*

```
upwardFlag = false
  dropdownStatus() {
this.showDropDown = !this.showDropDown;

var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;

var dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown-toggle')

var bodyRect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top,
  offset = dropdown.getBoundingClientRect().top,
  topOffset = offset - bodyRect;
var relativeOffset = topOffset - scrollTop;
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

var dropdownMenu = document.querySelector('.dropdown-menu')
if (relativeOffset > (windowHeight/2)) {
  console.log('show upward', dropdownMenu);
  this.upwardFlag = true
} else {
  this.upwardFlag = false
  console.log('show downward', dropdownMenu);
}
```

}

*app.component.html*

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" #dp (click)="dropdownStatus()">
  Cool dropdown
<span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu open" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" *ngIf="showDropDown"  [ngClass]="{'showDropDown': 'open'}" [class.reverse]="upwardFlag===true">
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Action</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

You can check it in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bbtxkq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Angular has not yet created the HTML element when you query it, your code is faster than Angular template checking ;)

**Two solutions**

1. Make a reverse variable and do `[class.reverse]="reverse"` on your component.
2. Use `[hidden]="!showDropdown"` rather than *ngIf, then it will be available in the DOM.

- By the way, you could use a `@ViewChild('.myClass') dropdown : ElementRef;` to access the element in a more "Angular Way".